# Azure AD/Office 365: Create similar groups for two different domains

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I have two domains registered in Azure AD, domainA.com and domainB.com, and I want to create two similar Groups for them:

- support@domainA.com
- support@domainB.com

How can I do that?

Im trying code like below via Microsoft Graph, and first Group is created successfully. However there is an error when adding the second group for domain B:

> "Another object with the same value for property mailNickname already
> exists"

```
        public async Task CreateSupportGroups()
        {
            // Create the group for domain A
            await UpdateDefaultDomain("domainA.com");
            await AddNewGroup("Support group for Domain A");

            // Create the group for domain B
            await UpdateDefaultDomain("domainB.com");
            await AddNewGroup("Support group for Domain B");
        }


        public async Task AddNewGroup(String groupName)
        {
            var group = new Group
            {
                Description = "Testgroup",
                DisplayName = groupName,
                GroupTypes = new List<String>()
                {
                    "Unified"
                },
                MailEnabled = true,
                MailNickname = "support",
                SecurityEnabled = false,
                Visibility = "Private"
            };

            await graphClient.Groups
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(group);
        }

        public async Task UpdateDefaultDomain(String domainID)
        {
            var domain = new Domain
            {
                IsDefault = true
            };

            await graphClient.Domains[domainID]
                .Request()
                .UpdateAsync(domain);
        }
```

Comment: (1) Verify whether the above code path actually goes/updates to the domainB.com or not (2) If it doesnt help, then again redo the same calls for the new domain

Comment: I tried to do it via Office 365 Admin Center instead, just to see if it worked, but in last step for the second group it shows the same error message:"Another object with the same value for property mailNickname already exists"

Comment: it means you're trying to create the object in the same domain

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment.

Please make domainA.com as primary and create a group with displayname **support A** and mailnickname as **support**

Then make domainB.com as primary and create a group with displayname **support B** and mailnickname as **supportB** because if you create with mailnickname as **support**, it will throw below error :

[image]

After creation of Support B Group, edit the primary mail of the group to support@domainB.com. Even though it throws error, the primary mail of the group is updated.

Please refer below screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, yes that seems to work even though it throws error :) Do you know if it is possible to do the update of primary mail via code/microsoft graph after creation? This was meant to be implemented into a webapplication where mailnickname is dynamically set, so it would be much easier if can avoid logging into Office 365 Admin Center.

Comment: I tried via Graph API, I received the same error "Another object with the same value for property mailNickname already exists"